# KeyError when plotting ROC curve

Tags: python, roc

I am trying to plot the ROC curve for a multi label classification problem. 
My target column before giving it labels looked like:

```
TargetGrouped
I5
I2
R0
I3
```

This is part of the code used to plot the ROC:

```
    def computeROC(self, n_classes, y_test, y_score):
        # Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
        fpr = dict()
        tpr = dict()
        roc_auc = dict()

        # Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
        fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
        roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])

        # Plot ROC curve
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"],
                 label='micro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})'
                       ''.format(roc_auc["micro"]))
        for i in range(n_classes):
            plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], label='ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
                                           ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))

        plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
        plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
        plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
        plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
        plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
        plt.title('Some extension of Receiver operating characteristic to multi-class')
        plt.legend(loc="lower right")
        plt.show()

    lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()
    infoDF = infoDF.join(pd.DataFrame(lb.fit_transform(infoDF["TargetGrouped"]), columns = lb.classes_, index = infoDF.index))

#Extracted features and split infoDF dataframe => got X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test

    rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
    rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = rfc.predict(X_test)

    classes = y_train.shape[1]
    computeROC(classes, y_test, y_pred)
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-50-15a83ece5e44>", line 3, in <module>
    evaluation.computeROC(classes, y_test, y_pred)

  File "<ipython-input-49-526a19a07850>", line 18, in computeROC
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], label='ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'

KeyError: 0
```

I know it might be an issue with the format of the class in the `plt.plot()` but I don't know how to fix it.

**Update**

This is the code missing from the `computeROC()`:

```
        for i in range(n_classes):
            fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
            roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
```

Comment: What does `n_classes` contains ?

Comment: It's an `int`, it is 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is actually with the following line:

```
for i in range(n_classes):
            plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], label='ROC curve of class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
                                           ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))
```

`fpr` and `tpr` are dictionaries and the only key you initialized is `'micro'`. This for loop assigns integer values between `0` and `n_classes-1` to `i`, but you have never defined what `fpr[0]` and `tpr[0]` are (and I suspect you are thinking of them as lists, but this is just speculation).